# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'graph_df' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, local

The code gets a coefficient and uses it to amend a DF below. It makes the use of another function which is scaling() and that works fine. Once this code runs, if I get it to print the final result, **new_df** it does that successfully but fails to return me the **new_df** and throws the error, below:

```
def scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date):

scaling_dict = scaling(normalised_graph_points_on_xaxis(company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date),
                       coefficient, delta, company_name)

print(scaling_dict)

sub_mse = scaling_dict.get('Sub_MSE')
add_mse = scaling_dict.get('Add_MSE')

if delta > 0.0001:

    if abs(add_mse-sub_mse) > 0.05:

        if add_mse > sub_mse:
            coefficient = coefficient + delta
            scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)

        elif add_mse < sub_mse:
            coefficient = coefficient - delta
            scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)

    else:
        delta = delta/2
        scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)
else:

    new_coefficient = coefficient

    print('Co-efficient:', new_coefficient)

    graph_df = normalised_graph_points_on_xaxis(company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)

    print(graph_df)

    for index, row in graph_df.iterrows():
        new_df = graph_df
        graph_df.set_value(index, twitter_sentiment, row[twitter_sentiment] * coefficient)

return new_df
```

Error

```
File "/Users/Pankaj/PycharmProjects/untitled/scaling_sentiment_graph.py", line 52, in scale_for_all_companies
scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)
File "/Users/Pankaj/PycharmProjects/untitled/scaling_sentiment_graph.py", line 67, in scale_for_all_companies
return graph_df
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'graph_df' referenced before assignment
```

I have seen similar posts like this but none of them caters for this specific case. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: If `if delta > 0.0001:` is `True`, `new_df` never comes into existence, so you can't `return` it.

Comment: Sorry, the error is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_df' referenced before assignment`

Comment: And the first delta that I pass in the function is 0.01 which is bigger than 0.001 but throughout the program, the delta keeps decreasing.

Comment: Yes, and my previous comment still stands as true. `if`/`else` is mutually exclusive, and if the `if` branch is true, there's no such thing as `new_df`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call this recursively. I'm not sure why, and you need to use `return` to do so.

Comment: I understand what you mean but the delta is initially 0.01 but eventually, it keeps decreasing and the idea is when the delta is less than 0.0001 then capture the coefficient in else part and use it to change the df.

Comment: I am trying to call this recursively but would also want to get the coefficient at the end of the function should the delta goes too low, i.e., 0.0001.

Comment: Put `return` to all `scale_for_all_companies`. So it becomes `return scale_for_all_companies(...`. Because even if your recursion ends, you just lose the result and try to return `new_df`, which is not initialized.

Comment: Also you need to be sure that `graph_df.iterrows()` will never be empty.

Comment: I put the `return scale_for_all_companies(....)` in the end and then called the function with another call to the function separately, as a result the program runs forever which is understandable as when it hits the return it kicks off again @Sklert

Comment: After debugging, it seems that once, `for index, row in graph_df.iterrows(): ` block runs the code then goes back to `else: delta = delta/2` block and then returns the **new_df**. That obviously mean that the **new_df** was never initialised and hence the error. Any idea why it jumps back to else block at all? Thanks

Comment: What does "in the end" mean? I meant to put `return` to every `scale_for_all_companies(....)` in your code in question =)  By the way,  check if these conditions `if delta > 0.0001` and   `if abs(add_mse-sub_mse) > 0.05:` can be changed to `False` in recursion

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
def scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date):

    scaling_dict = scaling(normalised_graph_points_on_xaxis(company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date),
                           coefficient, delta, company_name)

    print(scaling_dict)

    sub_mse = scaling_dict.get('Sub_MSE')
    add_mse = scaling_dict.get('Add_MSE')

    if delta > 0.0001:

        if abs(add_mse-sub_mse) > 0.05:

            if add_mse > sub_mse:
                coefficient = coefficient + delta
                return scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)

            elif add_mse < sub_mse:
                coefficient = coefficient - delta
                return scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)

        else:
            delta = delta/2
            return scale_for_all_companies(coefficient, delta, company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)
    else:

        new_coefficient = coefficient

        print('Co-efficient:', new_coefficient)

        graph_df = normalised_graph_points_on_xaxis(company_name, company_code, start_date, end_date)

        print(graph_df)

        for index, row in graph_df.iterrows():
            new_df = graph_df
            graph_df.set_value(index, twitter_sentiment, row[twitter_sentiment] * coefficient)

    return new_df
```

And it is better to do two more things: Firstly, initialize somehow `new_df` before `graph_df.iterrows()` to be sure that if `graph_df.iterrows()` is empty, you will not crash again. Secondly, check if `if abs(add_mse-sub_mse) > 0.05` can be False, so recursion will not run forever.

One more thing is that

```
new_df = graph_df
graph_df.set_value(index, twitter_sentiment, row[twitter_sentiment] * coefficient)`
```

You changed `graph_df` after `new_df` and then return `new_df`, so your changes to `graph_df` are not useful. Check this one. Maybe you wanted to put firstly `graph_df.set_value` and then `new_df = graph_df`?

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Thanks, @Sklert. Putting return where I call my `scale_for_all_companies` did help and now it returns the dataframe I'm looking for. Also, good observation about the `new_df = graph_df
graph_df.set_value(index, twitter_sentiment, row[twitter_sentiment] * coefficient)`
I completely missed it. Thank you for all your help :)